# React Native - Passing fetch data to Modal and using StackNavigator with Modal

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mobile

In here I have two problems. **First** is I'm trying to fetch dome data from my **api** and then pass this data to modal upon tapping a button. I have tried to use "state" and then declare that state like;

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      tbl: [],
      tbl_no: null,
    }
  }
  fetchTblOccpd = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://192.168.***.***:****/PndngVRoutes/Occupied/');
    const json = await response.json();
    this.setState({ tbl: json })
    this.setState({ tbl_no: json })
  }
  render() {
    return (
        .....
        <PndModal
          modalVisible = { this.state.modalVisible }
          setModalVisible = { (vis) => { this.setState({ modalVisible: vis }) }}
          tbl_no         = { this.state.tbl_no }
        />
    )
  }
```

But this didn't work. I'm targeting to fetch a data and pass it to my **Modal**.

Sample

[image: Target UI]

My **Second** question is after passing some data to Modal, I'm targeting to navigate to another screen/view from my modal.

here's my code

```
export default class PndModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            pnd_Data: [],
            modalVisible: props.modalVisible,
        };
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: nextProps.modalVisible,
            tbl_no: nextProps.tbl_no,    //This is the data I'm trying to pass.
        })
    }
    fetchOrdered = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.254.***:****/PndngVRoutes/PendingView/" + this.state.tbl_no);
        const json = await response.json();
        this.setState({ pnd_Data: json })
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchOrdered();
      }
    _onPressItem = () => {
        this.setState({
            modalVisible: false,
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal>
                <View>
                    <View>
                        <View>
                            <Text>Table No: { this.state.tbl_no }</Text>
                            <FlatList
                                data = {this.state.pnd_Data}
                                numColumns = { 2 }
                                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                                renderItem = {({ item }) =>
                                    <View>
                                        <Text>{ item.menu_name }</Text>
                                    </View>
                                }
                            />
                            <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress = { () => this.props.navigation.navigate('pend') }>      // This is my navigation code
                                <Text>Add Order</Text>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to answer both questions at once. So starting with the first one, what's not working?

Comment: in my first question, I'm trying to fetch some data from my api and then view it on the screen, upon tapping a button -- the data should be passed on modal. Now, in my case it's not. I'm not sure if my fetch code is wrong or in my modal code.

Comment: Does the modal show when you tap on the button? If it does, is the modal showing any data or nothing at all?

Comment: It doesn't at all sir, sometimes it shows error like; "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {tbl_id}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: In the case of your response, that would point to the fact that you're attempting to render the response from the json directly that is `{json}` instead of for ex. `{json.tbl_id}`

Comment: oww yes sir, it does remove the error. But my modal is still empty. BUUT! if I use { tbl_no = json[0].tbl_id } it does now show a data but not the data I'm expecting. The expected output is like in my sample picture where there's number from api, if I tap/click 2 then 2 will pass to modal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180455/discussion-between-kadeer-and-purple-violet).

Answer (score 0):

Hello  Am  not  too use to  react native but  i think is must  be the same as react  ,  for  the solution to  your  problem ,  i think you  should  use reusable component . then create  then pass your data  as a props.

Here  is an  example in react.

```
//My reusable component
    const Modal=(props) =>{


            return (

              <div>
                {props.data}
              </div>



            );
        }


    }
```

Then  you call  your reusable component  then pass  the results from the api  to  it.

```
<Modal
       data ={this.state.pnd_Data}   
  />
```

for the second question you can  just  add link  that  will navigate you ....  there  will be no problem for that .

you can read about reusable component here 
https://itnext.io/react-component-class-vs-stateless-component-e3797c7d23ab